# Как залогинить юзера в Symfony 3?

Tags: php, http, symfony, symfony3

В Symfony 3 посылает запрос на авторизацию пользователя на внешний сервис, при успешном запросе возвращается токен и данные пользователя. 
Как залогинить ответ сервиса ?
Спасибо!

Comment: Используя эти данные и залогинить. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Manitikyl я не знаю как имено

Comment: @Arzek если у вас есть таблица пользователей, то записать пользователю токен, который вам предоставили, записать время, которое он действует.

Comment: @StereoFlo нет таблицы, все данные из АПИ

Comment: получается, что для этих токенов, нужно завести таблицу, либо их хранить по-другому. смысл в том, что раз сервис выдает токен, значит с ним и нужно делать обращения

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос, хоть и давний, ответы жаль вызывают недоумение. Наверняка вы уже решили проблему, однако на случай похожего вопроса пару строк напишу.

Из уже готовых рецептов я бы рекомендовал посмотреть вот сюда https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle
Однако для понимания происходящего внимательно прочитать и перечитать для просветления соответствующий раздел https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html
И ссылки внизу. Это сложно, но единожды осилив вы реально сможете без бандлов сделать практически любой вид аунтификации под ваши нужды.